# How to print multiple lines in C, with popen?

Tags: c, popen

How to print multiple lines in C, with `popen`?
So I don't know how to print the rest of the lines
It's for a school project and I don't know what to do. The input file contains only a word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main() {
    FILE *f, *fp;
    int MAX=256;
    char buf[MAX];
    
    f=fopen("input", "r");
    
    if(!f){
        fprintf (stderr,"no input \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fgets(buf,MAX,f);
    char cmd[MAX];
    sprintf(cmd, "find ~ -name %s 2>/dev/null", buf);
    
    if ((fp=popen(cmd, "r"))==NULL){
        perror("perror hiba");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pclose(fp)==-1) perror("pclose error");
    
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is just one line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You treat the file pointer (`fp`) from `popen` exactly the same as you do the file pointer `f` from `fopen`; you can read a line with `fgets()` and then print it out with `printf`

Comment: You probably mean `fclose(f);` instead of `close(f)`. Depending on the input and preconditions I either don't get any output or I get error messages from `find`. This is what I expect because 1. the code doesn't process the data that could be read from `fp` and 2. the data read by `fgets` may include a newline. Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the preconditions like existing files and directories and the actual and expected output. Make sure you run exactly the same code you show in the question. Use copy&paste.

Comment: better than fclose() pclose() instead.... pclose() does a waitpid(), which fclose() doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the OP's actual problem is straightforward, but I wanted to add a few extra notes that they didn't ask about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main() {
    FILE *f, *fp;
    int MAX=256;
    char findpath[MAX];
    
    f=fopen("input", "r");
    
    if(!f){
        fprintf (stderr,"no input \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fgets(findpath,MAX,f);
    char cmd[MAX];
    sprintf(cmd, "find ~ -name %s 2>/dev/null", findpath);
    
    if ((fp=popen(cmd, "r"))==NULL){
        perror("perror hiba");
        exit(1);
    }

    char copybuf[MAX];
    // do the copy from the process to the output place
    while (fgets(copybuf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL)  // read from popen
    {
        // maybe do some other processing on each line
        fputs(copybuf, stdout);
    }

    if (pclose(fp)==-1) perror("pclose error");

    fclose(f);  // not close(f) -- hat tip to Bodo
    return 0;
}
```

A minor change was the first buffer is now `findpath` rather than `buf` - it's easy to get your buffers mixed up with generic names, so getting a good name can help avoid some of these. Using `cmd` was a great choice for that buffer.

Also: the current code will not do well if the filename read from the `input` file has a space in it (here, assume "my file"):

```
    find ~ -name my file 2>/dev/null
```

that won't do what you expect, and though spaces are not super common on the Linux platform, it's something to be aware of.

A partial fix would be

```
sprintf(cmd, "find ~ -name '%s' 2>/dev/null", findpath)
```

which protects against spaces, but what if the filename has a single quote on it?

In practice this is really hard to get right.

But finally, and I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader, what happens if your input file contains:

```
some_directory; rm -rf ~
```

Note the semicolon! What happens?

If that `input` file is from an untrusted source, you have to be SUPER careful.

Comment: "from an untrusted source, you have to be SUPER careful." is because the code will contaminate buffer or memory stack of computer?

Comment: .... because it could run an arbitrary command that could cause damage. That's what my `some_directory; rm -rf ~` example is about.